# How to Use Google Places API to search for “apartments near me”

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places

On a google search box, I type “apartments near me”.
How can I return the same result set using places API?

I have tried the following but I get slightly different results

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=aparments+near+me&location=30.423648,-97.683151&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY

The lat/long values used correspond to the “near me” location that I used

I’ll appreciate any help to point me towards getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

For searching Point Of Interests, you may use Nearby Search, please refer to the example below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=apartment&keyword=apartment&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking at the places API and I don't see a place type called "Apartment" - https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types
I had considered using "real_estate_agency" but results are not same as with the URL in the question